# Как передать аргумент через URL в views

Tags: javascript, python, django, url

Здравствуйте.

Скажите пожалуйста, как передать аргумент из ссылки URL в функцию views?
То есть, у меня на странице имеется следующее:`{% url 'posts:response_search' 123 %}`

Как передать число 123 в функцию views, если формат сгенерированного url должен быть статическим, то есть без добавления аргумента в адресную строку. Например, вот так:

```
    url(r'^response_search/$', views.response_search, name='response_search'),
```

Но все же аргумент должен как-либо передоваться. Заранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать post запросы.
Для этого можно использовать либо формы, либо ajax запросы.
В случае с формой html код будет таким:

```html
<form action="{% url 'posts:response_search' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="parameter" value="123">
</form>
```

Если использовать ссылку на других элементах, стоит использовать ajax:

```js
$('link').add('click', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'posts:response_search' %}",
    data: {
      'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
      'parameter': '123'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    method: "POST",
    success: function(response) {
      // Здесь можно выполнить код после получения успешного ответа
      console.log('Response status is: ', response.status);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Поскольку будет осуществляться передача данных необходимо использовать токен -->
{% csrf_token %}
<a id="link">Click</a>
```

В view response_search получить переданный параметр можно будет получить:

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

def response_search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        parameter = request.POST.get('parameter')
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status': 'ok'}))
    else:
        # Обработать запрос get
```

Answer (score 0):

Передавай через GET `{% url 'posts:response_search'%}?q=123`. Это сделает ссылку `/response_search/?q=123`.

В коде принимаешь это число через `q = request.GET.get('q')`.

Для поиска обычно делается так.

Если используешь форму ввода, то:

```
<form action={% url 'posts:response_search'%}>
<input name=q>
<submit>
</form>
```

Метод GET не рекомендуется для запросов, которые могут изменить состояние твоего приложения. Для редактирования лучше всеж использовать POST.